# center element using the Horizontal Timeline | Slick timeline

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I am making use of this slick library, but when only having two elements in the timeline then it is not shown correctly and it does not look centered, I have been changing the javascript values to see if I can make the timeline work correctly but so far I have not been successful. this is my html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 column">
    <div class="loading-bar__wrapper">
      
      <div class="loading-bar">
        <div class="loading-bar-bullet"></div>
        <div class="loading-bar-bullet"></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="labels">
        <div>
          <p>Apresentação do produto e construtora | Campeche</p>
          <a href="#" class="qb-button">Veja o conteúdo</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Conheça o bairro | Campeche</p>
          <a href="#" class="qb-button">Veja o conteúdo</a>
        </div>

      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the repository of the library that uses the timeline https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#settings and this is the codepen of the timeline https://codepen.io/perikan/pen/vjwXyg